# Spinner background white when doing android:Theme.Holo

Tags: android, android-layout

In Android 5.0 the Spinners have a white background when using android:Theme.Holo instead of android:Theme.Holo.Light

Holo.Light theme: (Working fine)

[image: Holo.Light theme]

Holo theme: (Not working)

[image: Holo theme]

Code:

```
<Spinner
android:id="@+id/dialog_mc_major_cat"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1" />
```

Themes:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="textColor">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/spinnerStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Dark" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
    <item name="textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/spinnerStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="spinnerStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem">
    <item name="android:padding">5dp</item>
</style>
```

I haven't tested it yet, but I believe that this works fine pre 5.0

Answer (score 0):

I tried it and for some reason, works fine if use

```
 <style name="AppTheme.Dark" parent="android:Theme.Holo">

</style>
```

without the added customizations on device and emulator

Comment: Which emulator Android did you use?

Comment: @Andrew121007 Android 5.0 - Nexus One - emulator